# How can I compare and filter two fields in the same document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My data is like this (I have taken out unnecessary fields and only left the dates in):

```
[
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T12:35:51.833Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "2022-09-01T05:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "2022-08-04T05:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "2022-09-01T05:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "2022-09-06T05:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T12:55:12.018Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "1919-11-30T07:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "1919-11-30T07:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "1926-11-30T07:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "1919-11-30T07:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "1919-11-30T07:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "1919-11-30T07:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "1919-11-30T07:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "1919-11-30T07:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T13:49:20.639Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "2022-09-15T05:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "2022-09-12T05:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T13:58:02.755Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "2022-09-13T05:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "date": "2022-08-20T05:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {}
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T14:17:04.947Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "2022-09-12T05:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T14:17:49.489Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "2022-09-13T05:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T14:19:26.068Z",
    "scans": [{}],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T14:20:07.569Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "2022-09-12T05:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T14:33:17.783Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "2022-08-15T07:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T14:33:41.050Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "2022-08-19T07:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T14:34:03.172Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "2022-09-07T07:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T15:28:23.723Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "2022-08-19T05:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T15:28:49.211Z",
    "scans": [
      {
        "date": "2022-09-09T05:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

I would like to get back the same list of documents but filtered according to these:

1. Include documents that have at least one scan where there is **no date** field.
2. Include documents that have scans where the **date is before 90 days** of the date field of the document.
3. Include documents that have scans where the **date is after** the date field of the document.

Bottom line is that I am trying to find documents with "incorrect" scans. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Please update your question to replace the link to sample data with formatted json in your question.

Comment: @rantao I have edited the question now. If you can help with this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following aggregation query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "diffData": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$scans",
          "as": "item",
          "in": {
            "$dateDiff": {
              "startDate": {
                "$toDate": "$$item.date"
              },
              "unit": "day",
              "endDate": {
                "$toDate": "$date"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          diffData: {
            $elemMatch: {
              "$eq": null
            }
          }
        },
        {
          diffData: {
            $elemMatch: {
              "$gt": 90
            }
          }
        },
        {
          diffData: {
            $elemMatch: {
              "$lt": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "diffData"
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U3Q0CAydeyQ)

In this query, we create a new field called `diffData`, where we store the difference between the scan date and the root date in days. Finally, we filter the elements, based on the criteria specified.

Comment: This worked flawlessly. I had no idea about the `$map` operator. I was trying to do a similar thing but with `$filter` and I was kind of stuck. This helps a lot. Thanks!